# Image display behind the gallery on the website on viewing on apple product like iPhone and iPad but display normally in all other devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ios

I have a couple of websites with a gallery section.

The gallery section on the website is https://ksuskalology.com/gallery and https://walingfulbariguesthouse.com.np/gallery

On the gallery, on clicking the image, the image goes behind the gallery only on apple products like `iPhone` and `iPad` but it works normally on android mobile and computer/pc.

I have a 3rd website -> https://lotussoft.com.np/gallery it is working normally on all devices too. I use the same `CSS` `simpleLightbox.css`, `aos.css` on all 3 websites.
I could not understand and figure out why the other 2 websites function differently than expected.

Is it related to the `jquery` version? I've used jquery 2.2.3 on waling fulbari guest house website and on lotussoft.com.np but on the lotussoft website, it is working fine but on guest house website is not working correctly.

I will appreciate it a lot if someone could find the error on my 2 websites.

Thanks in advance. I will appreciate for your help.

Comment: Without the code it is difficult to tell what the error is. Must likely is a cross-browser issue because the galleries don't work on some of the browsers I use.

Comment: @EdyEspinal to include all code is long, so I've provided the link for 2 websites which has issues with iPhone and iPad but on a third website, there is no issue code is same. I think It is by jquery.